# Arithmetic overflow on progress bar

Tags: vb.net

This ftp upload fragment is causing an "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" error for certain size files on the bWorker.Report Progress line

```
Dim fileStream() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim requestStream As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    For offset As Integer = 0 To fileStream.Length Step 1024
        bWorker.ReportProgress(CType(offset * ProgressBar1.Maximum / fileStream.Length, Integer))
        Dim chSize As Integer = fileStream.Length - offset
        If chSize > 1024 Then chSize = 1024
        requestStream.Write(fileStream, offset, chSize)
    Next
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What are the values of offset, ProgressBar1.Maximum and fileStream.Length when you get the error? Have you tried `CDbl(offset) / fileStream.Length * ProgressBar1.Maximum`?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Vb.net - whats the visual studio equivalent of console.log in a browser?! How can I see those values in debug mode as it runs?

Comment: That modified expression worked! Thanks

Comment: I've written it up as an answer for you. Note that the CDBl() was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the value of `offset * ProgressBar1.Maximum` becomes greater than [Integer.MaxValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (2147483647).

You can avoid the overflow by performing the calculations in a different order:

```
bWorker.ReportProgress(CType(offset / fileStream.Length * ProgressBar1.Maximum, Integer))
```

And it just so happens that CType(x, Integer) can be shortened to CInt(x), so you could write the shorter:

```
bWorker.ReportProgress(CInt(offset / fileStream.Length * ProgressBar1.Maximum))
```